# TextView fling animation Android

Tags: android, textview

Right now, I am able to remove textviews by flinging without any animation. How would you go about animating TextViews on flings to show this action?

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        layout.removeView(textView)
    } 
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        layout.removeView(textView);
    }
});
```

Each blue rectangular box are textviews.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code so that we can see what you have right now. Layout would be nice also.

Answer (score 0):

Android views have ViewPropertyAnimator class which will work it out for you if you are looking for some simple animations.
In your case, the simplest way to do this would be to call `TextView`'s `animate()` inside your `onFling()` method.

```
boolean isHidden;    
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    // ... fling check
    float velocity = Math.abs(velocityX / 8000f);
    long duration = (long) (100 / velocity); // calculate duration based on velocity
    textView.animate().translationX(isHidden ? 0 : 500).alpha(isHidden ? 1 : 0).setDuration(duration).start();
    isHidden != isHidden;
}
```

Although, this kind of animation will be triggered at the moment user's touch released, so this might be not exact behavior he expects to see.
In this case, you might want to combine your animation logic with `onScroll()` method